# convert sql query to laravel

Tags: mysql, php

I have an sql qyery.

```
SELECT rt.id, rt.type, rt.total_no_of_rooms
     , SUM(r.no_of_rooms) as "reserved rooms" 
     , rt.total_no_of_rooms - SUM(r.no_of_rooms) as "rooms available"  
FROM Roomtypes rt 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Reservations r 
    ON r.roomtype_id = rt.id 
    AND '2018-04-11' >= r.check_in 
    AND '2018-04-12' <= r.check_out
GROUP BY rt.id, rt.type, rt.total_no_of_rooms
```

can anyone tell e how to convert it to laravel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query is generated from [midnightcowboycoder.com](http://www.midnightcowboycoder.com). Don't forget to replace backtick with a single quote.

```
DB::select(`rt.id`,`rt.type`,`rt.total_no_of_rooms`)
        ->addSelect(DB::raw(`SUM(r.no_of_rooms) as reserved rooms`))
        ->selectSub(`rt.total_no_of_rooms`, `rooms available`)
        ->selectSub(`-`, `rooms available`)
        ->selectSub(`SUM`, `rooms available`)
        ->from(`Roomtypes as rt`)
        ->join(`Reservations as r`, function($join) {
            $join->on(`r.roomtype_id`, `=`, `rt.id`)
                ->on(`2018-04-11`, `>=`, `r.check_in`)
                ->on(`2018-04-12`, `<=`, `r.check_out`);
            })
        ->groupBy(`rt.id`)
        ->groupBy(`rt.type`)
        ->groupBy(`rt.total_no_of_rooms`)
        ->get();
```

Comment: its not workin. its show         "Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Connection::prepareBindings() must be of the type array, string given, called in "